# Solve the partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve

$$yU_{xy} + 2U_x = x \\
U=U(x,y)
$$

I have the solution to this question. I was told to integrate over $x$ at first. After integrating over $x$ I obtained:
$$yU_y + 2yU= (x^2)/2 +yC(y)$$
Then to solve further, one can use an integrating factor $m(y)=y$. My question is how to find this integrating factor?

Comment: I don't think you integrated over $x$ correctly. It should be
$$
yU_y + 2U = \frac {x^2}2 + f(y)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, that's how I'd solve it:
$$
yU_{xy} + 2U_x = x \\
yU_y + 2U = \frac {x^2}2 + f(y) \\
U_y + \frac 2y U = \frac {x^2}{2y} + \frac {f(y)}y
$$
General rule to find integrating factor is
$$
M(y) = e^{\int P(y)dy}
$$
if you equation looks like
$$
U_y + P(y)U = Q(x,y)
$$
In your case $P = \frac 2y$, so $M(y) = e^{\int \frac 2y dy} = e^{2\ln y} = y^2$. So multiply your equation to $M(y)$ to get full differential on the left
$$
y^2U_y+2yU = (y^2U)_y = \frac {x^2y}2+yf(y)
$$
After the integration over $y$
$$
y^2U = \frac {x^2y^2}4+F(y)+G(x) \\
U = \frac {x^2}4 + \frac{F(y)}y + \frac {G(x)}{y^2}
$$